# Why can final variables change in an Activity?

Tags: java, android, variables, android-intent, final

When using `intent.putExtra()` I create a final static String in another activity to get information from first activity.
Why does final variable in second Activity change after getting information from first activity ?

```
// in the first activity
Intent intent = new Intent (FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.EXTRA_String,"some text");
startActivity(intent);

// in the second activity
public final static String EXTRA_STRING = "extra string"
// in oncreate method
String a = getIntent().getExtras.get(EXTRA_STRING);
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). By their nature, `final` variables **can't** change. That's the point of them. There's some wiggle room where they can sometimes seem to change from their default all-bits-off value to another value, once, but other than that... Please show what you're doing and why you think a `final` var is changing.

Comment: add your codes too

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is changing? How do you know? Please provide more details.